# Get the visual position of the Pin in my GoogleMap

Tags: xamarin.forms

Any idea how to get the X,Y values of the Pin on my Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps
And by X,Y value I do not mean the latitude and longitude.
I'm asking for the Xamarin.Forms.Point object of my Pin.
Like the one we get from Map.Bounds.Center?

BTW: I have already tried Pin.Anchor and that keeps giving the Point (0.05,1) no matter where the Pin goes.

UPDATE 1: The Anchor Point (0.05,1) is basically the point on the image that should be placed on the coordinate.

Just for the Info:
The anchor point is specified in the continuous space [0.0, 1.0] x [0.0, 1.0], where (0, 0) is the top-left corner of the image, and (1, 1) is the bottom-right corner. (0.5,1) would be the center of the bottom edge of the image.

I am still looking for the distance thing. 
Will surely update once I get something.